# How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using parcelable?

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable

I'm trying to pass an object of type `Team` to another `Activity` in my app.

The `Team` class:

```
public class Team implements Parcelable {

    String teamName;

    //Name and Link to competition of Team
    TreeMap<String, String> competitions;
    //Name of competition with a map of matchdays with all games to a matchday
    TreeMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Event>>> matchDays;

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(teamName);
        dest.writeMap(competitions);    
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Team> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Team>() {
        public Team createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Team(in);
        }

        public Team[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Team[size];
        }
    };

    private Team(Parcel in) {
        teamName = in.readString();

        in.readMap(competitions, Team.class.getClassLoader());
    }
}
```

I get a RuntimeException when marshalling:

```
TreeMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Event>>> matchDays;
```

How can I pass the nested TreeMap along with the rest of the class?

Comment: What is Event? Is Event class serializable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String`, `TreeMap`, and `HashMap` all implement the `Serializable` interface.  You might consider implementing `Serializable` in your `Team` class and passing it between activities that way instead.  Doing so would make it so you that you can just load the object straight from the `Bundle` or `Intent` without having to manually parse them out.

```
public class Team implements Serializable {

    String teamName;

    //Name and Link to competition of Team
    TreeMap<String, String> competitions;
    //Name of competition with a map of matchdays with all games to a matchday
    TreeMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Event>>> matchDays;
```

No additional parsing code needed.

(Edit: `ArrayList` also implements `Serializable` so this solution is dependent on whether the `Event` class is Serializable or not.)

Comment: i will try that. thanks.. i was using parcelable because in some other threads they mentioned that Serializable is a rather dirty solution.

Comment: awesome!! works great and isnt slow even though i use Serializable. thanks!